# Implement a callback function inside a function

Tags: javascript, callback, jquery-callback

Say I have a function like the following.

```
loadXML('Method', requestString, function(callback){
   // The function as a callback parameter to loadXML goes here.

   // Here I am calling the callback function like this       
   if(callback != null){
       callback();
   }
});
```

But I want to define this callback function inside the loadXML function. So can I do this as following?

```
loadXML('Method', requestString, function(callback){
   // The function as a callback parameter to loadXML goes here.

   // Here I have to call the callback function like this, (do I?) which is a 
   // callback parameter to callback function of loadXML
   callback = function(){
       // The callback function implementation goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: I think that the `callback` is a parameter to `loadXML()` and isn't passed anywhere else. Did you try `console.log(arguments);` inside the function?

Comment: Why would you define a function and then not use it? And if you aren't passing it into the function, it isn't really a callback anyway. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: There is also a callback function for loadXML() which is defined there and I want to have another callback function to that function. Let me update the code then.

Comment: "Here I have to call the callback function like this" — That overwrites the callback function with a new function and doesn't call it at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to implement a callback function to a callback function inside the former callback function. I just want to know whether I am doing it right or what the right method is?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but what you are doing makes no sense and achieves nothing, so you are probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help you to understand the nested callbacks mechanism:

```
var loadXML;
var outerCB;
var innerCB;     

loadXML = function(method, requestString, cb) {
  // pass the innerCB implementation as argument to the outer cb
  if('undefined' !== typeof innerCB) {
    cb(innerCB);
  } else {
    // in case innerCB would not be defined
    cb(function() {
      console.log('hi from anonymous cb')
    });
  }
};


innerCB = function() {
  console.log('hi from innerCB cb!')
};

outerCB = function(callback) {
  if('undefined' !== typeof callback) {
    callback(); // innerCB();    
  } else {
    console.log('no cb passed, do something else')
  }    
}

loadXML('Method', 'abcd', outerCB) // hi from innerCB cb!
```

Comment: Thanx Villiam. I'd go with this & try this.